# How can I make custom key bindings work even while SSH-ed into another machine?

Tags: bash, cygwin, readline, putty

I've added

```
"\eOD": backward-word
"\eOC": forward-word
```

to my `.inputrc` to get ctrl-arrow key mappings sorted out in Cygwin allowing me to move forward and back fine.

When I SSH to any other Linux system, I lose this binding. Can anyone help?

I'm using PuTTYcyg 20101029, my terminal type is xterm, and I'm using Cygwin 1.7.9.

Comment: did you add these changes to the remote copy of .inputrc? Good luck

Comment: If i add the above to the remote machine it works, but i have 50+ remote machines that i log on to with different users, that wouldn't be an easy solution for me.

Comment: It would appear that when sshing, the shell you get is run on the remote machine, so it has no access to your local .initrc.  I took a quick look through the ssh man page and didn't find a way to pass args to the remote shell, but perhaps you can search for one and alias it in your .bashrc.  You could also write a script to append those lines to each of the remote machines' .initrc.

Comment: Thanks, i tried the same before i asked the question. There is no point fixing the remote machines because those machines change and are reinstalled regularly (test site) and also i don't want to go around modifying other machines user environments for my ease of use. I think there must be a cleaner way, i just wish i could find it.

Comment: @nickjb just write script which puts your .initrc/.bashrc on your remote machine and then makes real ssh. Then make `alias ssh=${HOME}/bin/spam_ssh.sh` on your script.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't see any way to make ssh always run commands (e.g. `bind -x '\eOD':backward-word` etc.) whenever you log in, if you can't depend on maintaining files such as .bashrc, .intputrc, or .ssh/rc on the remote hosts.  So how about this:

```
function ssh ()
{
  host=$1 ; shift
  scp ~/.inputrc $host:
  command ssh $host "$@"
}
```

This is kludgy and it will be a little slower, but it will give you your key bindings.